# Raise an error in a trigger without rolling back

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

Can the RAISERROR function be called so that it does not undo the transcription?
I created a trigger in which the task is to catch errors and only throw out the information that an error has occurred, but the raiserror withdraws transactions.

```
USE [ERPXL_TEST]
GO
/****** Object:  Trigger [CDN].[TraNag_Sprawdz_Magazyny]    Script Date: 14.02.2022 07:45:06 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      <Przemo>
-- Create date: <08.12.2021>
-- Description: <Trigger sprawdzający dokument PW czy dane są poprawne. >
-- =============================================
ALTER TRIGGER [CDN].[TraNag_Sprawdz_Magazyny]
   ON  [CDN].[TraNag] 
   FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    
    BEGIN
    DECLARE @typ AS INT
    DECLARE @numer AS INT
    DECLARE @flaga AS INT 
    DECLARE @centrum AS INT
    --DECLARE @operator AS VARCHAR (MAX)

    SET @typ = (SELECT TrN_GIDTyp FROM inserted) --pobiera aktualn typ dokumenty dla PW: 1617
    SET @numer = (SELECT TrN_GIDNumer FROM inserted) -- pobiera aktualny numer dokumentu
    IF (@typ = 1617 AND (SELECT s.SES_OpeIdent FROM inserted left outer join CDN.Sesje s ON s.SeS_SesjaId=TrN_Aktywny GROUP BY s.SES_OpeIdent)!= 'XLTECH' AND ((SELECT TrN_CechaOpis FROM inserted) != 'Odpady' ))-- sprawdza czy dokument jest PW i czy jest to integrator i sprawdza czy dokument nie posiada cechy odpady
        
    BEGIN
        SET @flaga = (SELECT CDN.TraElem.TrE_TypTwr FROM CDN.TraElem WHERE CDN.TraElem.TrE_GIDNumer = @numer AND CDN.TraElem.TrE_GIDTyp = @typ GROUP BY CDN.TraElem.TrE_TypTwr) -- sprawdza typ kartotek np: towar albo produkt
        SET @centrum = (SELECT s.SES_FrsID FROM inserted 
                left outer join CDN.Sesje s ON s.SeS_SesjaId=TrN_Aktywny GROUP BY s.SES_FrsID) -- Sprawdza aktualne centrum zabezpieczeń 

            IF exists (SELECT * FROM inserted WHERE TrN_GIDTyp = 1617 AND (TrN_MagDNumer = 2 OR TrN_MagDNumer = 11 OR TrN_MagDNumer = 3 OR TrN_MagDNumer = 4 OR TrN_MagDNumer = 12) AND @flaga !=1 AND @centrum !=1) -- sprawdza warunek czy wprowadzamy na stan magazynu towarów produkt
                
                BEGIN 
    
                    RAISERROR ('#CDN_INFO/# #CDN_1=Nie można wprowadzić kartoteki typu: "Produkt" na Magazyn towarów/# #CDN_2=Nieprawidłowy magazyn docelowy/# #CDN_3=Zmień dane w PW/#',16,1)
            
                END 
            
                
            IF exists (SELECT * FROM inserted WHERE TrN_GIDTyp =1617 AND (TrN_MagDNumer = 6 OR TrN_MagDNumer = 7 OR TrN_MagDNumer = 1) AND @flaga !=2 AND @centrum !=1) -- odwrotnie
                BEGIN
            
                RAISERROR ('#CDN_INFO/# #CDN_1=Nie można wprowadzić kartoteki typu: "Towar" na Magazyn produktów/# #CDN_2=Nieprawidłowy magazyn docelowy/# #CDN_3=Zmień dane w PW/#',16,1) 
                
                END
        END 
    END
END
```

Comment: In that case do not use raise error, just do what you want to do in this case. If you want a return value or message  do the insert inside a stored procedure and return the scope identity.

Comment: You realise you trigger is inherently flawed? You cannot assume that `INSERTED` has only a single row, it may have 0-N rows and you must handle that correctly.

Comment: You could try `SET XACT_ABORT OFF` because by default triggers are on and therefore rollback on any error. However it is recommended to no longer use `RAISERROR` and to use `THROW` instead which can make your situation a bit harder.

Comment: [This 3 part article](https://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part1.html) is essential reading when it comes to error handling.

Comment: You can use `RAISERROR` on severity level 1 and it won'r roll back, see https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=28645a7001cbd00f1e8a041fc4b1a4a3. Although why you would ever want to do this is another question, you could just look at the data you were inserting in the first place. And as mentioned, [your trigger is fundamentally broken](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2019/05/the-silent-bug-i-find-in-most-triggers/), I suggest you start again. `ON UPDATE` triggers should also compare the `deleted` table by primary key, in case there are rows not actually changed

Comment: My trigger doesn't change anything. Its only purpose is to check whether a given document is well prepared. The user in the program makes an inbound document and the trigger is only to check the correctness of the data. If there is something wrong it is supposed to trigger a popup. I checked the technical documentation of the program and the only option is RAISERROR.

Comment: _I checked the technical documentation of the program_ I struggle to understand that any application documentation will mention RAISERROR directly. But RAISERROR does not directly affect a transaction. It is the application that responds (correctly) to the error by rolling back the transaction. You cannot control that within a trigger. You should consult with your system vendor about your goal and the most appropriate way to accomplish it. Changing the schema is usually a TOS / license violation

Comment: Good thanks for the info. And as for the documentation, it is seriously mentioned directly about RAISERROR. I will contact the manufacturer, maybe he will suggest something.

Comment: @SMor In triggers `XACT_ABORT` is on by default, so an error >= level 16 will rollback.